# Time dilation on earth

Tags: general-relativity, potential, time-dilation

Im reading David Tong's notes on General Relativity and at one point, considering both $\frac{\Delta r}{r_A}\ll\,1$ and $\frac{2GM}{r_A}\ll\,1$ he obtains

$$T_B=t\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{(r_A+\Delta r)c^2}}\\\sim t\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{r_Ac^2}+\frac{2GM\Delta r}{r_A^2c^2}}\\\sim t\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{r_Ac^2}}(1+\frac{GM \Delta r}{r_A^2c^2})\\=T_A\left(1+\frac{GM\Delta r}{r_A^2c^2}\right)$$

I don't understand how the last expansion is carried out. This is by the way related to the time dilation effect due to Newtonian potential, just to give some context. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just use simple Binomial expansion. Take , $A^2=1-\frac{2GM}{r_Ac^2}$ and expand the square root term (use the above assumptions that $\Delta r/r_A<<1$ and $2GM/r^Ac^2<<1$ so that you can ignore higher order terms)

Comment: If you mean the operation that happens between lines 2 and 3, that's a Taylor expansion to first order. $\sqrt{1+x} \approx 1 + \frac{x}{2}$

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot guys, I don't know what I was thinking, sometimes I just forget the basic stuff.